# Issue with FindElement of Selenium Webdriver on AndroidDriver

Tags: android, selenium, webdriver

This question may looks similar to [Having Difficulty in finding Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780616/having-difficulty-in-finding-elements-using-xpath-and-css-in-selenium-android-we/15813240#15813240), but in my case the test running well with desktop browsers like firefox, ie driver but while come to Android driver it fails to find the element in emulator webdriver.

Note:Web page launched successfully, even it returns the page title name.

Comment: Please add your code and html to your question here.

Comment: @JulianHarty, let take the google page sample, even with that also i m having the element issue. [sample code](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/10/introducing-android-webdriver.html)

Comment: OK, how about adding details of the error(s) and the output of the get page source calls (based on the code I posted for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780616/having-difficulty-in-finding-elements-using-xpath-and-css-in-selenium-android-we/15813240#15813240 ) It's hard to diagnose your issue until you provide more details...